# How to Arrange a List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
data=[{'address': 'High Tech Campus 60', 'beta': 1.406659, 'ceo': 'Mr. Richard Clemmer', 'changes': -3.9400024, 'cik': '0001413447', 'city': 'Eindhoven', 'companyName': 'NXP Semiconductors N.V.', 'country': 'NL', 'currency': 'USD', ...}]
```

I have a dictionary.
Need to receive a list of dictionaries comma separated: [{},{},..]
How do I add them in a loop?
I tried to use append:

```
data_list.append(data.copy())
```

But it returns smth different: [[{...}]]

How do I get a list of such format:

```
[{'address': 'High Tech Campus 60', 'beta': 1.406659, 'ceo': 'Mr. Richard Clemmer', 'changes': -3.9400024, 'cik': '0001413447', 'city': 'Eindhoven', 'companyName': 'NXP Semiconductors N.V.', 'country': 'NL', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '41st, 1155 Rene-Leve...W Flr 4000', 'beta': 2.219123, 'ceo': 'Mr. Klaus Paulini', 'changes': -0.00999999, 'cik': '0001113423', 'city': 'MONTREAL', 'companyName': 'Aeterna Zentaris Inc.', 'country': 'CA', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '125 Summer Street', 'beta': 0.0, 'ceo': 'Dr. Jean-Pierre  Som...ossi Ph.D.', 'changes': 2.5800018, 'cik': '0001593899', 'city': 'Boston', 'companyName': 'Atea Pharmaceuticals, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '401 Charmany Dr', 'beta': 1.073689, 'ceo': 'Mr. Corey Chambas', 'changes': 0.0, 'cik': '0001521951', 'city': 'Madison', 'companyName': 'First Business Finan...ices, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '490 Arsenal Way', 'beta': 0.0, 'ceo': 'Mr. Marc A. Cohen', 'changes': -0.9699974, 'cik': '0001662579', 'city': 'Watertown', 'companyName': 'C4 Therapeutics, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': 'General-Guisan-Strasse 6', 'beta': 1.629418, 'ceo': 'Mr. Carlos Creus Moreira', 'changes': -0.09000015, 'cik': '0001738699', 'city': 'Zug', 'companyName': 'WISeKey Internationa...Holding AG', 'country': 'CH', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '508 W Wall St Ste 800', 'beta': 1.7762, 'ceo': 'Mr. Stephen Jumper', 'changes': -0.04999995, 'cik': '0000799165', 'city': 'Midland', 'companyName': 'Dawson Geophysical Company', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '955 Perimeter Road', 'beta': 0.0, 'ceo': 'Mr. Ravi  Vig', 'changes': -1.2900009, 'cik': '0000866291', 'city': 'Manchester', 'companyName': 'Allegro MicroSystems, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '490 Lapp Rd', 'beta': 1.138646, 'ceo': 'Ms. Geraldine Henwood', 'changes': -0.04999995, 'cik': '0001588972', 'city': 'Malvern', 'companyName': 'Recro Pharma, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '5 Haplada Street, PO Box 5011', 'beta': 1.396288, 'ceo': 'Mr. Guy Bernstein', 'changes': -0.9300003, 'cik': '0000876779', 'city': 'OR YEHUDA', 'companyName': 'Magic Software Enter...rises Ltd.', 'country': 'IL', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '111 West 33rd Street', 'beta': 0.0, 'ceo': 'Mr. Richard  Gumer', 'changes': -0.20249999, 'cik': '0001823323', 'city': 'New York', 'companyName': 'KL Acquisition Corp', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '2 Canal Park Ste 4', 'beta': 1.907176, 'ceo': 'Mr. Langley Steinert', 'changes': -1.4399986, 'cik': '0001494259', 'city': 'Cambridge', 'companyName': 'CarGurus, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '119 Standard St', 'beta': 1.592636, 'ceo': 'Mr. Ethan Brown', 'changes': -3.859993, 'cik': '0001655210', 'city': 'El Segundo', 'companyName': 'Beyond Meat, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '3854 American Way Ste A', 'beta': 0.502729, 'ceo': 'Mr. Paul Kusserow', 'changes': -1.5899963, 'cik': '0000896262', 'city': 'Baton Rouge', 'companyName': 'Amedisys, Inc.', 'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, ...]
```

Ok, it looks like initially I have not a dictionary but a list of dictionaries from one element. So how do I add another dictionary to the list after comma?

Upd: I managed to receive a list of dictionaries. It appeared it's not fully correct as some rows include additional fields. The list looks like this:`'currency': 'USD', ...}, 'code', 'status', {'address': '5` ...
How can I validate a list of dictionaries and make sure every dictionary matches predefined list of columns.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: `data` is a list of dictionaries not a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

```
data_list.append(data[0].copy())
```

You could also do

```
data_list = data_list + data
```

Comment: Thanks. I added comment. Originally I have a list with one dictionary. I just need to add more dictionaries to the list. And it should be comma separated...

Comment: Did you try my line ? Your dictionnary is inside a list, so you need to add the first element of that list, which is the dictionnary you want to add.

Comment: I just cannot save it to csv now... Getting error: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. The list: [{'address': 'High Tech Campus 60', 'beta': 1.406659, 'ceo': 'Mr. Richard Clemmer', 'changes': -0.19999695, 'cik': '0001413447', 'city': 'Eindhoven', 'companyName': 'NXP Semiconductors N.V.', 'country': 'NL', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {'address': '41st, 1155 Rene-Leve...W Flr 4000', 'beta': 2.219123, 'ceo': 'Mr. Klaus Paulini', 'changes': -0.04979998, 'cik': '0001113423', 'city': 'MONTREAL', 'companyName': 'Aeterna Zentaris Inc.', 'country': 'CA', 'currency': 'USD', ...}, {}, ...]

Comment: keys = data_list[0].keys()
with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='')  as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data_list)

Comment: I don't understand of what type is your object, try to print it and visualize it, try to print the shape of the object in order to understand what's going on

Comment: Sorry, in short I need a method to validate a dictionary. It appeared some of my dictionaries have a wrong number of keys and it corrupts the whole list. Do you know what's the fastest way to validate a dictionary based on some etalon dictionary for example (so it retrieves keys and values from the dictionary and based on it validates all other dictionaries)?

Comment: Nevermind, I check if dictionary with isinstance() and next check for number of keys with len(d.keys()) as it's always should be constant. Thank you.